# How to iterate through a table in HTML using beautifulsoup4 and store certain values in an array

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

How would you use a for loop to store the values of the parameters so as to print the results like so:

Focus Threshold Results:

```
{'Centre_Threhold:': 'max val', 'min val:': 'Corner Threshold:', 'max val': 'min val'}
```

Below is the part of the table I am working with and also the Python script I am testing.

HTML:

```
<tr><td class='label' colspan='2' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Threholds:</td>
</tr>

<tr><td class='label' colspan='2' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Focus_Threhold:</td>
</tr>

<tr><td class='label' colspan='2' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Centre_Threhold:</td>
</tr>

<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Minimum:</td>
    <td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Maximum:</td>
    <td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' colspan='2' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Corner_Threshold:</td>
</tr>

<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Minimum:</td>
    <td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Maximum:</td>
    <td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' colspan='2' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;MTF_Threshold:</td>
</tr>

<tr><td class='label' colspan='2' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Centre_Threhold:</td>
</tr>

<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Minimum:</td>
    <td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Maximum:</td>
    <td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' colspan='2' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Corner_Threshold:</td>
</tr>

<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Minimum:</td>
    <td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Maximum:</td>
    <td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' colspan='2' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Centration_Threhold:</td>
</tr>

<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;XY_Threshold:</td>
    <td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Rotation_Threshold:</td>
    <td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' colspan='2' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Color_Bar_Threshold:</td>
</tr>

<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Threshold:</td>
    <td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' colspan='2' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Color_Chart_Threhold:</td>
</tr>

<tr><td class='label' colspan='2' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hue_Threshold:</td>
</tr>

<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Minimum:</td>
    <td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Maximum:</td>
    <td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' colspan='2' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Luminance_Threshold:</td>
</tr>

<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Minimum:</td>
    <td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Maximum:</td>
    <td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0</span></td></tr>
```

Python:

```
focus_threshold_results = {}
for label in all_labels:
    if 'Focus_' in label.text:
        for sib in label.parent.next_siblings:
            if isinstance(sib, Tag):
                lab = sib.find('td', class_='label').text.strip()
                val = sib.find('td', class_='value').text.strip()
                focus_threshold_results[lab] = val
                if 'Maximum' in lab:
                    break
        break
print("Focus Threshold Results:    " + str(focus_threshold_results))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def set_res(res, last_labs, val):
    str = 'res'
    for l in last_labs:
        lstr = str
        str += "['%s']"%l
        exec("if '%s' not in %s: %s = {}" % (l,lstr,str))
    exec('%s = %s' % (str, val))

all_labels = soup.find_all("td", class_="label")
focus_threshold_results = {}
last_labs = []
for label in all_labels:
    if 'Focus_' in label.text:
        for sib in label.parent.next_siblings:
            if isinstance(sib, Tag):
                lab = sib.find('td', class_='label').text.strip()
                if 'MTF_Threshold' in lab: break
                valtd = sib.find('td', class_='value')
                last_labs.append(lab)
                if valtd:
                    val = valtd.text.strip()
                    set_res(focus_threshold_results, last_labs, val)
                    rem = -2 if 'Maximum' in lab else -1
                    last_labs = last_labs[:rem]
        break
print("Focus Threshold Results:    " + str(focus_threshold_results))
```

Comment: Tried that and it just prints out:

Focus Threshold Results:    {}

Comment: Are you sure you copied it well? It prints this to me: 
Focus Threshold Results:    {'Centre_Threhold:': {'Maximum:': 0, 'Minimum:': 0}}

Comment: Yes it works now must of copied it incorrectly. Okay see the way it only gets the Centre Threshold because it looks for the word Maximum then breaks? How can you also print the Corner results ans then break.

Comment: Output like this:

Focus Threshold Results: {'Centre_Threhold:': {'Minimum:': 0, 'Maximum:': 0} 'Corner_Threshold:': {'Minimum:': 0, 'Maximum:': 0}}

Comment: Returns this for me: 

Focus Threshold Results:    {'Centre_Threhold:': {'Minimum:': 0}}

Comment: Did you copy it well? :)

Comment: it was just the break statement. it didn't paste in the correct position ty <3

Comment: This is what I get: Focus Threshold Results:    {'Corner_Threshold:': {'Maximum:': 0, 'Minimum:': 0}, 'Centre_Threhold:': {'Maximum:': 0, 'Minimum:': 0}}.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, sanitize your HTML before the processing! You have typo in Centre_Threhold - should be Threshold. I changed the values for minimum and maximum in HTML to see the results:

```
s = """
<tr><td class='label' colspan='2' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Threholds:</td>
</tr>

<tr><td class='label' colspan='2' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Focus_Threhold:</td>
</tr>

<tr><td class='label' colspan='2' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Centre_Threhold:</td>
</tr>

<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Minimum:</td>
<td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Maximum:</td>
<td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>10</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' colspan='2' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Corner_Threshold:</td>
</tr>

<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Minimum:</td>
<td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Maximum:</td>
<td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' colspan='2' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;MTF_Threshold:</td>
</tr>

<tr><td class='label' colspan='2' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Centre_Threhold:</td>
</tr>

<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Minimum:</td>
<td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Maximum:</td>
<td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' colspan='2' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Corner_Threshold:</td>
</tr>

<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Minimum:</td>
<td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>4</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Maximum:</td>
<td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>5</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' colspan='2' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Centration_Threhold:</td>
</tr>

<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;XY_Threshold:</td>
<td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Rotation_Threshold:</td>
<td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' colspan='2' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Color_Bar_Threshold:</td>
</tr>

<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Threshold:</td>
<td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' colspan='2' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Color_Chart_Threhold:</td>
</tr>

<tr><td class='label' colspan='2' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hue_Threshold:</td>
</tr>

<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Minimum:</td>
<td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Maximum:</td>
<td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' colspan='2' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Luminance_Threshold:</td>
</tr>

<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Minimum:</td>
<td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Maximum:</td>
<td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;"><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>0</span></td></tr>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from bs4 import Tag
from pprint import pprint
import re

b = bs(s, 'lxml')

min_center_threshold = 0
max_center_threshold = 0

min_corner_threshold = 0
max_corner_threshold = 0

focus_threshold_results = {}
for tr in b.find_all('tr'):
    for c in tr.find_all('td', text=re.compile('.*?(Centre_Threhold)')):    # You have typo here (treShold)!
        minimum_value = int(c.find_next('td', text=re.compile('.*?(Minimum)')).find_next('td').text)
        maximum_value = int(c.find_next('td', text=re.compile('.*?(Maximum)')).find_next('td').text)

        min_center_threshold = min(min_center_threshold, minimum_value)
        max_center_threshold = max(max_center_threshold, maximum_value)

    for c in tr.find_all('td', text=re.compile('.*?(Corner_Threshold)')):
        minimum_value = int(c.find_next('td', text=re.compile('.*?(Minimum)')).find_next('td').text)
        maximum_value = int(c.find_next('td', text=re.compile('.*?(Maximum)')).find_next('td').text)

        min_corner_threshold = min(min_corner_threshold, minimum_value)
        max_corner_threshold = max(max_corner_threshold, maximum_value)

print(f"Focus Threshold: Centre_Threshold: ('{min_center_threshold}', '{max_center_threshold}'), Corner_Threshold: ('{min_corner_threshold}', '{max_corner_threshold}')")
```

Output:

```
Focus Threshold: Centre_Threshold: ('0', '10'), Corner_Threshold: ('0', '5')
```

Comment: There should only be one each of "Centre Threshold" & "Corner Threshold". 

I am trying to output like so:

Focus Threshold: Centre_Threshold: ('0', '0')}, Corner_Threshold: ('0', '0')}